# Code working with ternary operator but not with if else statements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

This javascript program works with ternary operator as expected but not with if else statements. What I am doing wrong?

I am trying to solve some basic javascript exercises but I am stuck at this question. 
https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercise-74.php

```
//Working code with ternary operator
    function all_max(nums) {
      var max_val = nums[0] > nums[2] ? nums[0] : nums[2];

      nums[0] = max_val;
      nums[1] = max_val;
      nums[2] = max_val;

      return nums;
      }
    console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
    console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
    console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```

// With if-else statement

```
  function all_max(nums) {
     if (var max_val = nums[0] > nums[2]) {
     return nums[0];
    } else {
     return nums[2];
  }

     nums[0] = max_value ;
     nums[1] = max_value ;
     nums[2] = max_value ;

return nums;
}
console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```

Comment: You've got `return` statements in the second version. A `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Comment: `variable assignment inside if it statement` just too ugly

Comment: @Pointy no luck even after removing return statement

Comment: @CodeManiac Good point. moved it outside if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be assigning the value in the body of the if/else statement, not within the comparison, so something like this should work for you:

```js
function all_max(nums) {
  let max_val = 0
  if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
    max_val = nums[0];
  } else {
    max_val = nums[2];
  }
  nums[0] = max_val;
  nums[1] = max_val;
  nums[2] = max_val;

  return nums;
}

console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works

```
      function all_max(nums) {
let max_val = nums[0] > nums[2]
     if (max_val) {
     return nums[0];
    } else {
     return nums[2];
  }

     nums[0] = max_value ;
     nums[1] = max_value ;
     nums[2] = max_value ;

return nums;
}
console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```

calculate max_val outside if condition and put result in if condition
let max_val = nums[0] > nums[2]

Comment: Check that `max_value` variable is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Variable declaration within `if` statement not allowed. Remove it.

Try this if you want only max value

```js
 function all_max(nums) {
   if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
         max_value =  nums[0];
   } else {
         max_value = nums[2];
   }
   return max_value;
 } 
 console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
 console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
 console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```

if you want all the elements in the array to be set to max value, then use this

```js
function all_max(nums) {
     if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
             max_value =  nums[0];
     } else {
             max_value = nums[2];
     }
     nums[0] = max_value;
     nums[1] = max_value;
     nums[2] = max_value;
     return nums;
}
console.log(all_max([20, 30, 40]));
console.log(all_max([-7, -9, 0]));
console.log(all_max([12, 10, 3]));
```